# select tag dynamically not working

Tags: php, jquery, html

[image]

As you can see in the image. there are a category list which is dynamicaaly printed with php loop. but it is not selected any thing.

html code

```
<div class="mini_width_left">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="quick_name" tabindex="2" placeholder="Name"/>      
  <input type="text" name="email" id="quick_email" tabindex="4" onblur="quickcheckEmail(this.value);" placeholder="Email" />
  <select value="1" name="category" id="category" tabindex="6"> 
    <option selected="selected">Select category</option>    
    <option value="84">Electronic Weighing Scale Balance &amp; System</option>
    <option value="85">Point of sale (POS) System</option>
    <option value="86">Self-Service KIOSK</option>
    <option value="87">GPS Clock</option>
    <option value="96">Milk Analyser</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="mini_width_right">
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="quick_phone" tabindex="3" maxlength="10" onKeyPress="return isNumberKey(event);"  placeholder="Phone" />
    <input type="text" name="location" id="quick_location" tabindex="5" placeholder="Location" />    
    <select name="category12" id="category12" tabindex="7"> 
        <option>Select product</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

php code

```
<select name="category" id="category" tabindex="6"> 
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Select category</option>    
    <?php foreach($decode as $key => $value) { ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $value['category_id']; ?>"><?php echo $value['name']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

All list are coming, but nothing is selected.

Comment: dont know if this is the problem but why `value="1"` in `select value="1"`

Comment: where are your <form></form> tags?

Comment: please provide an example where we can see the error, this html renders (at least in jsfiddle) with the dropdown having a default value visible

Comment: Change to this : `<option value="">Select category</option>    `

Comment: @VictorRadu : i want to select an option by default. in this case "select category" must be selected. but it is not.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen : i have also tried with removing the 'value="1" ' but also it is not working

Comment: @NazishFraz see my updated comment, and definitely remove the value attribute from the select element, there is no such thing

Comment: @D.Wells : there are form tags. but form is too long so i have just focused on select tag.

Comment: This is wrong, <option selected="selected">Select category</option>, it should be this way: <option selected>Select category</option>

Comment: @nacho actually it is not, both are valid, arguably selected="selected" might be redundant but it is NOT wrong it's just the XHTML way

Comment: @VictorRadu : follow this link http://www.essae.com/ goto to the bottom of page. you will find a "send enquiry" form. you can see there that what is the error.

Comment: @nacho : both are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a javascript on your page changing the value of your select, try loading the page without js

Comment: if($('#category').css('display') != 'none'){
  if(category.trim()=="")
  {
   alert("Please Select Category");
   document.getElementById("category").value="";
   document.getElementById("category").focus();
   return false;
  }
 }

Comment: for category. only this jquery is calling. nothing else

Comment: did you load the site without js? (disable js in your browser console)

Comment: I got the solution. there were js issue.